# installing sims3 expansion pack

Tags: drivers, wine, games

After hours of trying different manuals on the internet I finally managed to install the sims 3 base game. Now I would like to add an expansion pack, the sims 3 pets, but if I follow the same instructions again it will create a separate virtual drive. When the installer is lounged is says that I need the sims 3 base game installed first. That is probably because I am trying to create a new virtual drive and therefore it can not see that the base game is already installed.

Should I chose to update an existing driver, with the sims 3 base game, or does that delete the data already in there. How can I make these two drivers communicate with each other so it can detect the base game?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, yes you do need to choose 'update existing driver' and install the expansion pack in the same driver as you installed the base game. Pretty logical maybe.